Swagger OpenAPI issue with bundling up files
I am using swagger-cli to bundle my openapi.yaml file that has refs to other .yaml files in sub dirs. The api documentation when I spin up the server works without any issues and displays all the schema, properties, descriptions, routes, parameters etc. However, when I try to make a call to any endpoint it fails with TypeError
The command im using for swagger-cli
swagger-cli bundle ./app/config/openapi.yaml --outfile _build/openapi.yaml --type yaml

Main openapi.yaml file
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Toy App
  description: 'A toy app'
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:4000
  description: 'Local development server'
tags:
- name: reports
  description: CRUD operations for reports
  externalDocs:
    description: Find out more
    url: http://swagger.io
paths:
  "/api/product/{productId}/prices":
    $ref: './products.yaml#/~1api~product~1%productId%7D~prices'

This is my products.yaml file
/api/product/{productId}/prices:
    get:
      tags:
      - prices
      summary: Gets all prices for a product
      description: Returns an array of prices for a product
      parameters:
        - $ref: './parameters.yaml#/parameters/ProductId'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: List of product prices fetched successfully
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: './schema/product.yaml#/Products'
        '400':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/400'
        '401':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/401'
        '403':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/403'
        '404':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/404'

Here is my openapi.yaml file that gets created in the _build directory
'/api/product/{productId}/prices':
    get:
      tags:
      - prices
      summary: Gets all prices for a product
      description: Returns an array of prices for a product
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/paths/~1product~1%7BproductId%7D~1prices/parameters/0'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: List of product prices fetched successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/paths/~1api~1products/post/responses/200/content/application~1json/schema'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/paths/~1api~1me/get/responses/400'
        '401':
          $ref: '#/paths/~1api~1me/get/responses/401'
        '403':
          $ref: '#/paths/~1api~1me/get/responses/403'
        '404':
          $ref: '#/paths/~1api~1me/get/responses/404'

parameters/yaml
parameters:
  ProductId:
    name: productId
    in: path
    description: The ID of the product
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string
      example: '1abc'

responses.yaml
responses:
  '400':
    description: Invalid request
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: './schema/error.yaml#/schemas/ApiErrorResponse'
  '401':
    description: Unauthorized request
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: './schema/error.yaml#/schemas/ApiErrorResponse'
  '403':
    description: Forbidden request
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: './schema/error.yaml#/schemas/ApiErrorResponse'
  '404':
    description: ID not found
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: './schema/error.yaml#/schemas/ApiErrorResponse'

This is the error when I make a get request to the endpoint
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parameters'

I am so confused why the parameters ref is changed in the _build/openapi.yaml file when it clearly is not the same in the original one. Any help is appreciated. TIA

its just a copy paste mess up, but thanks for flagging

Seems like your JSON Pointers are invalid
Try these
# openapi.yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Toy App
  description: 'A toy app'
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:4000
  description: 'Local development server'
tags:
- name: reports
  description: CRUD operations for reports
  externalDocs:
    description: Find out more
    url: http://swagger.io
paths:
  "/api/product/{productId}/prices":
    $ref: './products.yaml#/~1api~1product~1%7BproductId%7D~1prices'

# products.yaml
/api/product/{productId}/prices:
    get:
      tags:
      - prices
      summary: Gets all prices for a product
      description: Returns an array of prices for a product
      parameters:
        - $ref: './parameters.yaml#/parameters/ProductId'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: List of product prices fetched successfully
          content:
            'application/json':
              schema:
                $ref: './product.yaml#/Products'
        '400':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/400'
        '401':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/401'
        '403':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/403'
        '404':
          $ref: './responses.yaml#/responses/404'

#parameters.yaml
parameters:
  ProductId:
    name: productId
    in: path
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string

#product.yaml
Products:
  type: object
  title: A Product Title
  description: A Product Description
  required:
    - ProductId
    - ProductType
  properties:
    ProductId:
      type: string
    ProductType:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string


btw, you didn't provide your responses.yaml so adjust those paths accordingly

thanks for the comment. i just updated the question with my parameters.yaml file (please note that it still fails with the TypeError)

is the type error the same one for parameters?

i included the parameters schema in my answer, i didn't have the responses.yaml available in your original question

updated the question with responses.yaml, but this inclusion shouldnt really mattter since its related to the parameters key of the path where the error is coming from. if you compare original openapi and _build openapi, you will notice that the parameter refs are different

can't say for certain, but I imagine it starts with the invalid pointer in the path $ref and the tooling just rewrites the other paths to whatever it finds

try fixing the first pointer and rebuild it

this pointer parameters: - $ref: './parameters.yaml#/parameters/ProductId', is correct, otherwise the validator would flag it and the field would not appear in the api doc on the server in first place

i'm talking about the path pointer.. it's resolving the wrong path item! look at the tags, they are wrong too.  get:       tags:         - client

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Might not be the ideal answer but, I've never had such issues using redocly/cli. Just saying.
